# HQL - List country and fetch all the state and currency

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I wanted to list all countries to fetch all the respective state and currency.

*ConfFacade.java*

```
public Result<List<Country>> listCountries() {
    try {
        String HQL = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM Ocountry o LEFT JOIN FETCH o.ostate, o.ocurrency";
        List<Country> list = em.createQuery(HQL).getResultList();

        return new Result(Status.SUCCESS, list);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Result<>(Status.ERROR, Exception.GENERAL, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

ConfFacadeLocal.java

```html
public interface ConfFacadeLocal {
    
    public Result<List<Country>> listCountries();
    
}
```

This is the *jsp* that I use and code it:

*listCountries.jsp*

```html
<%
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            ConfFacadeLocal confFacadeLocal = (ConfFacadeLocal)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/tomin");

            Result<List<Country>> result = confFacadeLocal.listCountries();
            if(result.isUnsuccessful()) {
                throw new Exception(result.getErrMsg());
            }
            
            List<Country> countryList = result.getObject();
            if(countryList == null) {
                throw new Exception("Error.");
            }
            out.print("OK");
            
    %>
            
            <table border="1" align="center" style="width:50%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>country code</th>
                    <th>currency code</th>
                    <th>state id</th>
                    <th>state description</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody><%              
            for (Ocountry country : countryList){ %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=country.getOccode()%></td>
                    <td><%=country.getOcurrency().getOcucode()%></td>
                    <td><%=country.getOstate().getOsid()%></td>
                    <td><%=country.getOstate().getOsdesc()%></td>

                </tr><%
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.print("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } %>
        
              
     
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is the error that I get:

```html
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getOstate()
  location: variable country of type com.ejb.entities.conf.Country
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 42 in the jsp file: /country/listCountries.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getOstate()
  location: variable country of type com.ejb.entities.conf.Country
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
 at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From your *JSP* error logs, I guess you missed to declare the `#listCountries` method to the `ConfFacadeLocal` bean interface.

Adding the needed method declaration to the interface should resolve the issue:

```java
public interface ConfFacadeLocal {

  // other API methods ...

  public Result<List<Country>> listCountries();

}
```

Comment: Sorry is my bad for not list out this part. I have declare to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

There (line 41):

```
 <td><%=currency.getOcucode()%></td>
```

you are using the currency variable, which has not been declared.

It seems that currency is an attribute of the 'Country' class in you program, so maybe you should write instead

```
 <td><%=country.getCurrency().getOcucode()%></td>
```

You have the same problem with the 'state' variable.

Comment: I have update my code and It seem like showing the same error for state variable.

Comment: `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getOstate()`  Check your Country class and verify how you can access a state attribute.

Comment: i can access via ostateSet : public Set<Ostate> getOstateSet() {
        return ostateSet;
    }

    public void setOstateSet(Set<Ostate> ostateSet) {
        this.ostateSet = ostateSet;
    }

Comment: and one more error is due to failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tomin.ejb.entities.omin.conf.Ocountry.ostateSet, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: The JPA session that have been used to fetch the country list has been closed at the time you are rendering the jsp. The simpliest way to deal with that is to add the fetch=FetchType.EAGER attribute on the annotation that decorates the ostateSet field in the Country class -

Comment: yup. after i change the fetch = FetchType.EAGER it able to work. but still curious if i use LAZY then how should i code it?

Comment: you should manage to maintain the jpa session opened during the rendering of the jsp / It depends on how you application is structured. The "Open session in view" pattern is something very common for Hibernate applications, for example by using a Servlet filter - but I have no exemple on how it is achieved in pure JPA.